# Proguard does not keep package hierarchy in ZipEntry

Tags: java, jar, proguard

I have obfuscated my code using proguard. In the code I want to read all classes from a specified package with following code.

```
    URL directoryURL = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
            .getResource("com/test/ui/controller");
```

This code does not work because jar created by proguard does not keep package hierarchy. I write a code that reads entries from obfuscated jar.This is output.
See that class packages does not kept in zip file. So getResource() does not work.

com/test/ui/controller/a.class

com/test/ui/controller/c.class

com/test/ui/controller/b.class

com/test/ui/controller/d.class

When I run same code with an unobfuscated jar., here is output. Package level is kept in jar.Do you have any idea how can I tell Proguard to create jar by keeping package level.

com/

com/test/

com/test/ui/

com/test/ui/controller/

com/test/ui/controller/a.class

com/test/ui/controller/c.class

com/test/ui/controller/b.class

com/test/ui/controller/d.class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-keepdirectories solved my problem.

> Specifies the directories to be kept in the output jars (or aars,
>   wars, ears, zips, apks, or directories). By default, directory entries
>   are removed. This reduces the jar size, but it may break your program
>   if the code tries to find them with constructs like
>   "mypackage.MyClass.class.getResource("")". You'll then want to keep
>   the directory corresponding to the package, "-keepdirectories
>   mypackage". If the option is specified without a filter, all
>   directories are kept. With a filter, only matching directories are
>   kept. For instance, "-keepdirectories mydirectory" matches the
>   specified directory, "-keepdirectories mydirectory/*" matches its
>   immediate subdirectories, and "-keepdirectories mydirectory/**"
>   matches all of its subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

> -keeppackagenames [package_filter]
>
> Specifies not to obfuscate the given package names. The optional filter is a comma-separated list of package names. Package names can
>   contain ?, *, and ** wildcards, and they can be preceded by the !
>   negator. Only applicable when obfuscating.

(Source: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#obfuscationoptions)

Comment: As you seen, package name is already kept. So we can see com/test/ui/controller/a.class.The problem here, it just puts class level to ZipEntry.